# Only allow one radio button to be checked HTML

Tags: html

I have a series of radio buttons in which i'd only like 1 to be able to be selected. I have them all with the same name so I thought this would do the trick but i can still select all four.

```
<h1>Portion</h1>

            <input type="radio" name="portion_num" value="2" /> Two

            <input type="radio" name"portion_num" value="4" /> Four

            <input type="radio" name"portion_num" value="6" /> Six

            <input type="radio" name"portion_num" value="8" /> Eight
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because your name attribute syntax is wrong.

`name"portion_num"` should be `name="portion_num"`

http://jsfiddle.net/65ba8/

Answer (score 1):

Put them inside of form tags.

Like so

```
     <form>
       <input type="radio" name="portion_num" value="2" /> Two

        <input type="radio" name="portion_num" value="4" /> Four

        <input type="radio" name="portion_num" value="6" /> Six

        <input type="radio" name="portion_num" value="8" /> Eight
     </form>
```

Comment: Irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="portion_num" value="2" />Two
    <input type="radio" name="portion_num" value="4" />Four
    <input type="radio" name="portion_num" value="6" />Six
    <input type="radio" name="portion_num" value="8" />Eight
</form>
```